# How to Indexing a field without using mongo db sell command in Keystonejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I need to implement full-text search in keystone js . is there any way to add Index on a specific field without using MongoDB shell command?

I have added 
`index: true`
But it's not working.

Thanks